# Find the time complexity of a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

Why is the time complexity of this function O(n1*n2) when n1 is the length of s1 and n2 is the length of s2?

I tried to build an equation but failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(char* s1, int i1, char* s2, int i2) {
    if (s2[i2] == '\0')
        return 1;
    if (s1[i1] == '\0')
        return 0;
    if (s1[i1] != s2[i2])
        return f(s1, i1 + 1, s2, 0);
    return f(s1, i1+1, s2, i2+1);
}

void main() {
    printf("%d", f("hello", 0, "he", 0));
}
```

Comment: At least describe that the function is supposed to do.

Comment: Why do you believe it is n1*n2?

Comment: It's not `O(n1 * n2)` The call stack can only ever get `n1 - i1` deep and there's no backtracking.

Comment: @pnina: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

The function increments `i1` by `1` for both tail call, hence the time complexity is **O(n1)**.

Note that this function does not implement a variant of `strstr()` as it would fail to find a match for `f("aab", 0, "ab", 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let `a` be the first integer index where `s1[a] != s2[a]` ∧ `s1[a] != '\0'` ∧ `s2[a] != '\0'`

If `a` exists, then your function is **O(n1)**.

Else, it is **O(min{ n1, n2 })**.

---

In simpler terms, if one of your string is a right trimmed version of the other one, then the function will be O(n), with n the size of the substring.

Else, it will be O(n1).

---

To understand this, I would advise you to try some iterations of the function yourself, with a pen and a paper, at first without the last `if`.